Decreasing exponential
Consider the function $$f(x) = A e^{xB} e^{-Ce^x} (1 + O(e^{-x})),$$ where $ A, B, C \in \mathbb{R} $, under what conditions on $A, B,$ and $C$ will $f(x)$  be decreasing as  $x$ goes large? How do the signs and magnitudes of $B$  and $C$  influence the behavior of $f(x)$ at infinity, and what role does the small $O(e^{-x})$ term play in this context? Specifically, what is the relationship between $B$ and $C$  that ensures the function's derivative $f'(x)$ is negative for sufficiently large $x$?  
Any help or hint's would be so much appreciated!

why the tag analytic number theory? complex analysis? both are irrelevant to the question as stated.


"when $x$ gets large" but do you mean that $x>0$ ? 2) Gather the two exponential into $e^{xD}$ where $D=B-C<0$...


@JeanMarie My bad there is a typo on my question it should be $-Ce^x$. Sorry for the confusion
